# Dragging div elements and then switching places with another element

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to program a bejeweled like game in javascript but instead of clicking a jewel then clicking another jewel to make them switch positions, I want to the player to click on a jewel then drag to another jewel to make them switch places. In the code I use the variable orb as jewels.

```
function makeOrb(orb, x, y) {
    orb.className = "orb";
    var bejeweledarea = document.getElementById("bejeweledarea");
    bejeweledarea.appendChild(orb);
    var random = Math.round(Math.random() * (colors.length - 1));
    orb.style.backgroundColor = colors[random];
    orb.style.position = "absolute";
    orb.style.top = y + "px";
    orb.style.left = x + "px";
    orb.onmousedown = activate;
    if (activeSwitching) {
        orb.onmouseover = switchOrbs(activeOrb, orb);
    }
}

function activate() {
    activeSwitching = true;
    activeOrb = this;
}

function switchOrbs(orb, otherOrb) {
    var oldTop = orb.style.top;
    var oldLeft = orb.style.left;
    orb.style.top = otherOrb.style.top;
    orb.style.left = otherOrb.style.left;
    otherOrb.style.top = oldTop;
    otherOrb.style.left = oldLeft;
}
```

My could will register the activeSwitching as true but for some reason the mouseover event doesn't ever work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are now adding a `onmouseover` event to the orb that has just been clicked. I assume you want all the **other** orbs to have an `onmouseover` event that calls `switchOrbs`, right? Because you want to switch the orbs when the activated is hovered over an other orb.

You could add that mouseover event to *all* the orbs. In that function you then check if `activeSwitching = true`. If so, you perform the routine to switch. Otherwise you stop, since there is no activated orb and the program needs to wait for a `orb.onmousedown` / `activate()` call.

**Edit**: outline for the code

```
$(".orbs").on("mouseover", function() {
  // `this` is the orb that is being hovered
  if( currentActiveOrb != null ) {
    switch(this, currentActiveOrb);
  }
}).on("mousedown", function() {
  // `this` is the orb that is being clicked
  currentActiveOrb = this;
}).on("mouseup", function() {
  currentActiveOrb = null;
});

function switch(hovered, active) {
  // Code to switch the orbs.
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I want the other orbs to have the onmouseover event. How do I go about adding the event to all the orbs? Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: I added a pseudo-outline.